# Unable to get screenshot of Rich Text Area Field which contains images using html2canvas library

Tags: visualforce, javascript

Unable to get screenshot of Rich Text Area Field which contains images html2canvas

> Access to Image at xxx site from origin xxx site has been blocked by
>   CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource. Origin xxx site is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 0):

The [CORS standard](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/), implemented in the browser generates this error.

To fix the issue, include the following in your header block.

```
   <script runat=server>
   Platform.Load("core","1");
   HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST");
   HTTPHeader.SetValue("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
   </script>
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i) a related StackOverflow question, for more context.